# Como agregar la propiedad select2 con un .attr

Tags: c#, jquery, html5, asp.net-mvc-5

Buen día colegas, actualmente estoy haciendo una tabla donde voy agregando dinámicamente Rows al dar clic a un botón, pero el problema es que al principio tengo un select con la propiedad select2, pero cuando agrego un Row dinámicamente con mi botón se agrega el select pero sin la propiedad select2 y quisiera saber la forma de como agregarlo y que traiga select2.

Esta es la forma en la que agrego los Rows a la tabla

```
function agregaRows() {
    position++;
    $('#tbTablaRecetas')
    .append
    (
        $('<tr>')

        .append
        (
             $('<td>')
             .append
             (
             $('<Select>').attr('id', 'idEAN' + position).addClass('form-control')
             )
         )            
         .append
         (
              $('<td>')
              .append
              (
              $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').attr('id', 'piezas_' + position).addClass('form-control')
              )
         )
         .append
         (
         $('<td>')
              .append
              (
              $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').attr('id', 'ICD_' + position).addClass('form-control')
              )
         )
         .append
         (
              $('<td>')
              .append
              (
              $('<div>').addClass('btn btn-danger').text('Eliminar')
              )
         )
    )
}
```

Este es mi body

```
  <tbody id="tbodyDatos">
                <tr class="tr">
                    <td>
                        <select id="idEAN" class="form-control"></select>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Unidades, new { @class = "form-control", style = "z-index:0", autocomplete = "off" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Unidades, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.ICD, new { @class = "form-control", style = "z-index:0", autocomplete = "off" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ICD, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <div type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</div>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Y así le indico que el select que trae el id="idEAN" sea select2

```
 $('#idEAN').select2();
```

Así se ve cuando trae select 2 el primer registro
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando agrego un Row ya no se le aplica select2
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No olvides que los id _deben ser únicos_, probablemente por eso no se esté aplicando el select2 en la siguiente fila.

Comment: Por eso le agrego una posicion para que sean diferentes id, pero aun asi no jala amigo @padaleiana

Comment: Amiga* :) ¿Y modificaste `$('#idEAN').select2();`?

Answer (score 0):

Para que te funcione el **select2** en cada nueva fila debes decirselo después de hacer el `append` correspondiente, o bien antes de salir de la función.

Por lo tanto agrega esto justo antes de salir de la función:

```javascript
$('#idEAN' + position).select2();
```

Te dejo un snippet funcional para que lo ejecutes y compruebes por ti mismo:

```js
position = 0
function agregaRows() {
  position++;
  $('#tbTablaRecetas')
    .append($('<tr>')
      .append($('<td>')
        .append($('<Select>').attr('id', 'idEAN' + position).addClass('form-control'))
      )
      .append($('<td>')
        .append($('<input>').attr('type', 'text').attr('id', 'piezas_' + position).addClass('form-control'))
      )
      .append($('<td>')
        .append($('<input>').attr('type', 'text').attr('id', 'ICD_' + position).addClass('form-control'))
      )
      .append($('<td>')
        .append($('<div>').addClass('btn btn-danger').text('Eliminar'))
      )
    )
    $('#idEAN' + position).select2();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<table id="tbTablaRecetas">

</table>
<button onclick="agregaRows()">
Agregar fila
</button>
```